# Поиск максимума во вложенных словарях

Tags: python-3.x, словари

Есть словарь с вложенными словарями вида:

```
{
 'Иван': {'рост': '176', 'вес': '120', 'прибавилВвесе': '14'}, 
 'Вася': {'рост': '176', 'вес': '120', 'прибавилВвесе': '-5'}
}
```

И мне нужно узнать, у кого значение `'прибавилВвесе'` максимальное.

Kакую функцию применить, или придется через цикл искать?

Comment: не хотят верифицировать :(

Comment: Связанный вопрос [getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найти максимальное значение можно с помощью функции max:

```
data = {'Иван': {'рост': '176', 'вес': '120', 'прибавилВвесе': '14'}, 'Вася': {'рост': '176', 'вес': '120', 'прибавилВвесе': '-5'}}
print(max(data, key = lambda k: data[k]['прибавилВвесе']))
```